# [R-iGraph-Sfnetwork]: Is it possible to optimize this code for setting new weight in SfNetwork / iGraph

Tags: r, igraph, sfnetwork

While profiling my code I discovered that the part that sets the new weight in a graph 
 takes the most time to run.
Since I have to do it repeatedly on much bigger graph than in this example, the running time adds up.
Is it possible to optimize it?

Here is a mini example:

```
library(sfnetworks)
library(sf)
```

First I create an example **sf_network (iGraph)**:

```
net = as_sfnetwork(roxel, directed = FALSE) %>%
  st_transform(3035) %>%
  activate("edges") %>%
  mutate(weight = edge_length())
```

Then I select two nodes and search for a path between them:

```
paths = st_network_paths(net, from = 495, to = c(458, 121), weights = "weight")
```

I select on path (the edges of it) and:

```
edges<-unlist(paths$edge_paths[1])
```

This part takes the most time to run and if possible I would like to optimize:
Read the current weight of the edges, multiply it with 100 and set the new weight for the edges.

```
my_sfn<-set.edge.attribute(graph = net,name = "weight",index = edges,value =  (get.edge.attribute(graph = net,name = "weight",index = edges))*100)
```

Is it possible to optimize this part ?

**#update:**

One approach Im thinking about is to maybe make it in parallel:
Basically divide the edges vector on different cpus and work with it
but the problem is; as result I would get a list of graphs.

For example:

**edges** contains indices 456,432,124,567,854,235,789,111... (hypothetically)
I would divide the list by 2 and do a mlapply on the **sfn net**.

CPU1 -> apply -> 456,432,124,567 on sfn net -> results in a copy of a net with the weight of  456,432,124,567 edges changed
CPU2 -> apply -> 854,235,789,111 on sfn net -> results in a copy of a net with the weight of  854,235,789,111 edges  changed

Or one other approach I was thinking about : **sfnet** is a tbl_graph right? cant I use like future_apply on that **tbl_graph**?

**##update**

Parallel does not seem to bring an improvement in this case:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(parallel)

edges_chunks<-split(edges, ceiling(seq_along(edges)/(length(edges)/4)))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
new_net<-set.edge.attribute(graph = net,name = "weight",index = edges,value =  10000),
new_net_list<-lapply(edges_chunks, function(x)set.edge.attribute(graph = net,name = "weight",index = x,value =  10000)),
new_net_list<-mclapply(edges_chunks, function(x)set.edge.attribute(graph = net,name = "weight",index = x,value =  10000), mc.preschedule=TRUE,mc.cores = n.cores)
)


      min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
    750.120    887.842   1061.393   1036.850   1176.605   1769.066   100
   3111.609   3609.785   4086.067   4002.368   4435.135   7891.939   100
 204809.249 208559.875 213134.374 209879.946 211954.072 320525.229   100
```

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Hi Andrea!

thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

I looked into it and the benefit of igraph approach disappears as soon as I have to work with gps coordinates instead of the indices themselves.

I checkt SF_Network code to see how you guys are doing it (find an indices to a gps coordinate) and made this benchmark.

The slowdown seem to be happening in the part where I have to match a gps coordinate to indices which are required to find a shortest path.

So to gain speed i have to find a way to make the matching of coordinates to indices faster.

```
library(sfnetworks)
library(sf)
library(tidygraph)
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)


my_sfn = as_sfnetwork(roxel, directed = FALSE) %>%
  st_transform(4326) %>%
  activate("edges") %>%
  mutate(weight = edge_length())


start_lon<-7.572567248901512 
start_lat<-51.92503522221193 


ziel_lon<-7.68342049920836 
ziel_lat<-52.00488468255698

start_point = st_sfc(st_point(c(start_lon, start_lat)))
start_point<-start_point |> st_set_crs(4326)

dest_point = st_sfc(st_point(c(ziel_lon, y = ziel_lat)))
dest_point<-dest_point |> st_set_crs(4326)


node_geom_colname = function(x) {
  col = attr(vertex_attr(x), "sf_column")
  if (is.null(col)) {
    # Take the name of the first sfc column.
    sfc_idx = which(vapply(vertex_attr(x), is.sfc, FUN.VALUE = logical(1)))[1]
    col = vertex_attr_names(x)[sfc_idx]
  }
  col
}

valid_agr = function(agr, names, levels = sf:::agr_levels) {
  if (is.null(agr)) {
    new_agr = empty_agr(names)
  } else {
    new_agr = structure(agr[names], names = names, levels = levels)
  }
  new_agr
}

node_feature_attribute_names = function(x) {
  g_attrs = node_attribute_names(x)
  g_attrs[g_attrs != node_geom_colname(x)]
}


node_attribute_names = function(x) {
  vertex_attr_names(x)
  
}
node_agr = function(x) {
  agr = attr(vertex_attr(x), "agr")
  valid_agr(agr, node_feature_attribute_names(x))
}

nodes_as_sf = function(x, ...) {
  st_as_sf(
    as_tibble(as_tbl_graph(x), "nodes"),
    agr = node_agr(x),
    sf_column_name = node_geom_colname(x)
  )
}

weight <- edge_attr(my_sfn, "weight")


bench::mark(
  sfnetworks = {
    path1_sfn <- st_network_paths(my_sfn, from = st_nearest_feature(st_geometry(start_point), nodes_as_sf(my_sfn)), to = st_nearest_feature(st_geometry(dest_point), nodes_as_sf(my_sfn)), weights = "weight")
    edges <- path1_sfn$edge_paths[[1]]
    my_sfn_2 <- set_edge_attr(
      graph = my_sfn, 
      name = "weight", 
      index = edges, 
      value = edge_attr(my_sfn, "weight", edges) * 100
    )
    path2_sfn <- st_network_paths(my_sfn_2, from = st_nearest_feature(st_geometry(start_point), nodes_as_sf(my_sfn_2)), to = st_nearest_feature(st_geometry(dest_point), nodes_as_sf(my_sfn_2)), weights = "weight")
    path2_sfn$node_paths[[1]]
  }, 
  igraph = {
    weight <- edge_attr(my_sfn, "weight")
    path <- shortest_paths(my_sfn, from = st_nearest_feature(st_geometry(start_point), nodes_as_sf(my_sfn)), to = st_nearest_feature(st_geometry(dest_point), nodes_as_sf(my_sfn)), weights = weight, output = "both")
    weight[path$epath[[1]]] <- weight[path$epath[[1]]] * 100
    path <- shortest_paths(my_sfn, from = st_nearest_feature(st_geometry(start_point), nodes_as_sf(my_sfn)), to = st_nearest_feature(st_geometry(dest_point), nodes_as_sf(my_sfn)), weights = weight, output = "vpath")
    as.integer(path$vpath[[1]])
  }, 
  iterations = 15L
)
```

**Result**

```
# A tibble: 2 × 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result     memory     time       gc      
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>     <list>     <list>     <list>  
1 sfnetworks   37.2ms   38.3ms      26.2    2.08MB     4.02    13     2      497ms <int [37]> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
2 igraph       35.8ms   36.2ms      27.5    1.31MB     4.23    13     2      473ms <int [37]> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
```

Comment: Hi @Andreas. My suggestion here would be to ignore the sfnetworks wrappers (i.e. to_spatial_shortest paths and so on) and directly write your code your igraph function. In that way, the vector of weights can be specified using a generic numeric vector and you don't need to modify any attribute of the graph. If you want, I can provide an example.

Comment: Hi @agila I can try;  an example would be great!

Comment: @agila, `set.edge.attribute` and `get.edge.attribute` are already quite efficient `igraph` functions.

Comment: @Waldi with the suggestion of agila there seems to be another curlpult for the slowdown: the matching of GPS coordinate to indices in the graph. See my latest update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to summarise here one example plus some ideas that could be
useful to improve the computational efficiency of your code.
First, load some packages

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(sf)
  library(tidygraph)
  library(igraph)
  library(sfnetworks)
})
```

The following code creates a toy network with 1e5 nodes and approximately 7e5
edges. I didn’t test the code with larger networks.

```r
set.seed(1)
my_graph <- play_geometry(n = 100000, radius = 0.0066)
my_sfn <- as_sfnetwork(my_graph, coords = c("x", "y")) %>% 
  convert(to_spatial_explicit, .clean = TRUE) %E>% 
  mutate(weight = edge_length())
#> Checking if spatial network structure is valid...
#> Spatial network structure is valid
```

Now we try to replicate the code that you showed using sfnetworks + igraph.
First, we compute the shortest path between nodes 495 and 458

```r
path1_sfn <- st_network_paths(my_sfn, from = 495, to = 458, weights = "weight")
```

Let’s check the output (and, in particular, the node path)

```r
edges <- path1_sfn$edge_paths[[1]]
(path1_sfn$node_paths[[1]])
#>  [1] 495 336 399 506 558 621 667 898 903 647 493 392 256 185 248 439 380 458
```

The following code multiplies the weights of the relevant edges by 100

```r
my_sfn <- set_edge_attr(
  graph = my_sfn, 
  name = "weight", 
  index = edges, 
  value = edge_attr(my_sfn, "weight", edges) * 100
)
```

and, finally, we recompute the shortest path between nodes 495 and 458

```r
path2_sfn <- st_network_paths(my_sfn, from = 495, to = 458, weights = "weight")
```

and check the output

```r
path2_sfn$node_paths[[1]]
#>  [1] 495 288 336 249 506 538 621 649 881 898 977 970 831 619 750 535 587 439 300
#> [20] 380 481 458
```

Now we restore the original weights and repeat the same operations as before
using only igraph code

```r
my_sfn <- my_sfn %E>% mutate(weight = edge_length())
```

0. Extract the weights

```r
weight <- edge_attr(my_sfn, "weight")
```

1. Compute the shortest path between nodes 495 and 458

```r
path <- shortest_paths(my_sfn, from = 495, to = 458, weights = weight, output = "both")
```

2. Check the output just to be sure that we extract the same nodes as before

```r
as.integer(path$vpath[[1]])
#>  [1] 495 336 399 506 558 621 667 898 903 647 493 392 256 185 248 439 380 458
```

3. Adjust the weights

```r
weight[path$epath[[1]]] <- weight[path$epath[[1]]] * 100
```

4. Compute shortest path

```r
path <- shortest_paths(my_sfn, from = 495, to = 458, weights = weight, output = "vpath")
```

5. Check again

```r
as.integer(path$vpath[[1]])
#>  [1] 495 288 336 249 506 538 621 649 881 898 977 970 831 619 750 535 587 439 300
#> [20] 380 481 458
```

Restore the original output and benchmark the two approaches:

```r
my_sfn <- my_sfn %E>% mutate(weight = edge_length())

bench::mark(
  sfnetworks = {
    path1_sfn <- st_network_paths(my_sfn, from = 495, to = 458, weights = "weight")
    edges <- path1_sfn$edge_paths[[1]]
    my_sfn_2 <- set_edge_attr(
      graph = my_sfn, 
      name = "weight", 
      index = edges, 
      value = edge_attr(my_sfn, "weight", edges) * 100
    )
    path2_sfn <- st_network_paths(my_sfn_2, from = 495, to = 458, weights = "weight")
    path2_sfn$node_paths[[1]]
  }, 
  igraph = {
    weight <- edge_attr(my_sfn, "weight")
    path <- shortest_paths(my_sfn, from = 495, to = 458, weights = weight, output = "both")
    weight[path$epath[[1]]] <- weight[path$epath[[1]]] * 100
    path <- shortest_paths(my_sfn, from = 495, to = 458, weights = weight, output = "vpath")
    as.integer(path$vpath[[1]])
  }, 
  iterations = 15L
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 sfnetworks    1.34s    2.85s     0.355   117.2MB     1.11
#> 2 igraph     135.91ms 280.26ms     2.52     37.1MB     1.35
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Just two final notes:

1. As we can see, the "pure igraph" code is much faster than the combination of the two packages (and this is not a surprise, sfnetworks is just a wrapper around igraph). Therefore, if you really need to focus on computational efficiency, I would suggest using sfnetworks just for the bare minimum (i.e. as_sfnetwork + some pre-processing morpher) and running any shortest path algorithm with pure igraph code;
2. Nevertheless, the igraph code is slightly more verbose and requires a little bit more preprocessing and care. You may need to readapt something before you can translate your sfnetwork code into pure igraph code.